# Mutable Protocol array type

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-protocols, computed-properties

I have declared a protocol which contains all the attributes of a network call.

```
protocol EndPoint {
  var url: URL { get }
  var method: HTTPMethod { get }
  var parameters: Parameters? { get set }
  var headers: HTTPHeaders?
}
```

I am providing default implementation in the extension of protocol

```
extension EndPoint {
  var queryItems: QueryPairItems? {
    nil
  }
     
  var encodingType: ParameterEncoding {
    URLEncoding.default
 }

 var method: HTTPMethod {
    .get
    }
  }
```

i want to mutate the headers. I have a struct which conform to this protocol and updates the values. but i am having trouble with updating it like i want to add the incoming headers in the existing ones provided in the default values.

The struct which confirm and changes the parameters is like this

```
struct APIConstructor: NetworkEndPoint {

var url: URL
var method: HTTPMethod
var parameters: Parameters?

init(urlString: String,
     method: HTTPMethod = .get,
     parameters: Parameters? = nil,
     headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil) {
    
    url = URLGenerator.path(endPoint: urlString, service: service)
    self.method = method
    headers?.forEach({ self.headers?.add($0) })
    print("+++++++++ \(self.headers)")
}
    var headers: HTTPHeaders? {
    get {
        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [HTTPHeader(name: "Content-type", value: contentType.rawValue)]
        
        if let token = LoggedUserDetails.shared.token {
            
            headers.add(HTTPHeader.authorization(bearerToken: token))
        }
        
        return headers
    }
    
    set {

        print(headers)
    }
  }
}
```

But when i pass some headers as input, it doesn't update the value i have tried setting it in the setter like newValue.foreach {} but that also includes the default values i have already provided. How do i mutate the headers and add the newValues with the existing values?. I am using alamofire

Comment: NetworkEndPoint vs EndPoint, I assume they are really the same? Also you have implemented a `get` for `headers` that will only return the default values so that is why it isn't working. Move that code to the `init`

Comment: Do you mean you want the headers to be set to the thing that you are returning in the getter, _plus_ the headers that are passed in through the initialiser parameter?

Comment: @Sweeper yes you're right. that is what i want

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what you said makes sense because everytime get will return those values which are passed in the computed property. so i should just remove the getter right?

Comment: @UsamabinAttique Not only should you remove the getter, you should also make `headers` a stored property, not a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code you've provided

```
set {
   print(headers)
}
```

doesn't change the value. So you need to update the setter.

If you want any endpoint to have some sort of predefined headers, then I'd suggest something like this:

```
protocol EndPoint {
  var url: URL { get }
  var method: HTTPMethod { get }
  var parameters: Parameters? { get set }
  var headers: HTTPHeaders?
}

extension EndPoint {
   var queryItems: QueryPairItems? { nil }
   var encodingType: ParameterEncoding { URLEncoding.default }
   var method: HTTPMethod { .get }
   var defaultHeaders: HTTPHeaders? { <#someDefaultHeaders#> }
   var headers: HTTPHeaders? { defaultHeaders }
}
```

This way any object that conforms to `EndPoint` would have default headers, that can be extended by using `defaultHeaders` property like so

```
struct SomeEndpoint: EndPoint {
   var headers: HTTPHeaders? { 
      <#yourCustomHeaders#>.merging(defaultHeaders)
   }
}
```

I don't think that injecting some extra headers after the endpoint object has been created is a good idea. This object is used somewhere, and `headers` are extracted there, so I suggest moving this "mutation" logic into that place of your codebase.